# Rounding to 3 decimal places in a distance formula

Tags: c#, math, double, rounding

I have a double that I need rounded to 3 decimal places. I'm not sure how to accurately implement Math.Round. This is what I have so far:

```
double distance= Math.Sqrt(deltax + deltay);
Math.Round((decimal)distance, 3);
Console.WriteLine("Distance :" + distance);
```

Comment: Did you ignore the return value in line two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return value of Math.Round (already noted by [Uwe Keim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim)) and remove the decimal cast.

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(10.438295 + 10.4384534295);
Console.WriteLine("Distance :" + Math.Round(distance, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't round it using `Math.Round()`, round it in the output string formatter:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(deltax + deltay);
Console.WriteLine("Distance :{0:f3}", distance);
```

You almost never want to use `Math.Round()` for formatting output.

The reason is, if you are formatting output to 3 decimal places, you normally want to show trailing zeros to indicate how many DPs you are displaying.

For example, given

```
double x = 0.1;
```

Then

```
double rounded = Math.Round(x, 3);
Console.WriteLine(rounded);
```

will display `0.1`, whereas

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f3}", x);
```

will display `0.100`, which instantly tells the user that it was rounded to 3 dps.

If you want to remove trailing zeroes from the output, then you *could* use `Math.Round()`, but I'd use the `###` string formatter:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.###}", x);
```

This will ouput `1.2345` as `1.235` and `1.0` as `1`.

Comment: Or `$"Distance :{distance:f3}"`.

Comment: @UweKeim Indeed, but I wanted to avoid having to use the latest version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that 'Math.Round' rounds the number but if it's an integer result, you will get just the integer. With '{0:f3}' it will always display 3 decimals. (7 vs 7.000)

Comment: @Odrai Yes, which is a major reason for preferring the string formatting instead of `Math.Round()` which, as I said, you almost never want to use for formatting output.